# Already registered user name can be registered

Tags: python, html, django

Already registered user name can be registered in user creation form. I'm making Django application.
I wrote in views.py

```
def regist(request):
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)

def regist_save(request):

    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST" and regist_form.is_valid():
                regist = regist_form.save(commit=False)
                regist.is_staff = True
                regist.save()

                advertisements = Advertisement.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'registration/detail.html', {'advertisements': advertisements})
```

in regist.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/accounts/regist_save/" method="POST">

          <div class="form-group-lg">

            <label for="id_username">Username</label>

            {{ regist_form.username }}
            <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.username.help_text }}</p>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group-lg">

            <label for="id_email">Email</label>

            {{ regist_form.email }}
            <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.email.help_text }}</p>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group-lg">

            <label for="id_password">Password</label>

            {{ regist_form.password1 }}
            <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password1.help_text }}</p>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label for="id_password">Password(Confirmation)</label>

            {{ regist_form.password2 }}
            <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-lg regist">Register</button>

              <input name="next" type="hidden" />

            </div>
          </div>
          {% csrf_token %}

        </form>
```

in forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password1','password1',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Now in this user registration form, if I write already registered user name&email&password, these data is not registered but detail.html is load. I wanna show alert if I do so like "this user name is already registered". Why isn't my web page not my ideal one? Why can I resist already registered user name in my site? How should I fix this? I did not make User model in models.py.

Comment: Can you post your model and form? i suggest making email/username unique in model itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import Q

if request.method == "POST" and regist_form.is_valid():
    try:
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username', None)
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email', None)
        # if username or email already exist in the User table
        # if you want to use the user object you can make it

        # if you want to check username and email with or, then it would work
        user = User.objects.get(Q(username=username) | Q(email=email))
        # if you want to check username and email with and, then it would work
        user = User.objects.get(username=username, email=email)

        # else if you have no username but only email you just only filter for email
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)

        # else if no need for user detail, you can do this
        User.objects.get(Q(username=username) | Q(email=email))
        messages.warning(request, 'That detailed use is already available.')
        # return to register form / template page
        # whatever your page is
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # save the user
        regist = regist_form.save(commit=False)
        regist.is_staff = True
        regist.save()
```

Comment: thx ur answer.I have a question.Didn't use user of User.objects.get(username=username, email=email)?

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please write a clear message?

Comment: It means user variable is not used in codes.Is it right?

Comment: yeah it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a custom model and extending auth. By default if unique is set to true, django fill raise a form error during submit itself.

In models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

PS: Override where ever required. Also suggest looking in the django tutorials, and [simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html). Mr Vitor has an easy tutorial

Comment: I think you failed to mention; if you inherit AbstractUser you need to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in setting file : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: thx ur answer.I did not make User model in models.py.How should I fix tis?I updated my question.